# Laravel 5.6 Notification Broadcast is queued but not sent

Tags: laravel, pusher

I have the following Notification set up

BillProcessed.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Bill;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;

class BillProcessed extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $bill;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Bill $bill)
    {
        $this->bill = $bill;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        // Only send mail if this feature is turned on
        return config('features.bill_processed_mail', false) ? ['mail', 'broadcast', 'database'] : ['broadcast', 'database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->greeting("Hello {$notifiable->name},")
            ->line('A new Bill has been processed!')
            ->action('View Bill', url('/bills/' . $this->bill->id))
            ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the database representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'message' => 'New Bill Processed',
            'bill' => $this->getBillStub(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the database representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        return new BroadcastMessage([
            'data' => [
                'message' => 'New Bill Processed',
                'bill' => $this->getBillStub(),
            ],
        ]);
    }

    protected function getBillStub()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->bill->id,
            'due_date' => $this->bill->due_date->format('m-d-Y'),
            'site_code' => $this->bill->account->site->code,
            'site_name' => $this->bill->account->site->name,
            'type' => $this->bill->account->types->first()->name,
            'created' => $this->bill->created_at->format('m-d-y H:i:s'),
        ];
    }
}
```

This is working beautifully on my local machine but when I put it up on our staging environment it is having issues.

First off, the mail is going to the log just fine. The database is getting filled up with notifications as well. The broadcast is being picked up by the queue but it just sits there like this:

[image]

It's not failing or timing out, it just sits there in this state. I have tried restarting Supervisor and still nothing.

I have also quadruple checked that I have the proper PUSHER information in my env file.

Comment: looks like its in pause state - you can try php artisan horizon:continue

Comment: I did all the horizon commands that were applicable. See answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for our staging environment we use APP_ENV=uat. If your not using "production" or "local" as your APP_ENV you need to publish the horizon configs and add your env to it like so:

```
   'environments' => [
        'production' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 3,
            ],
        ],
        'local' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 3,
                'tries' => 3,
            ],
        ],
        'uat' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 3,
                'tries' => 3,
            ],
        ],    
    ],
```

Otherwise horizon will not know which queue to listen to and will sit around doing nothing. Hope this helps!